# Can a stage of the cumulative hierarchy violate the partition principle?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

If we violate the partition principle and add to $\sf ZF$ the axiom that there exists a set $X$ that has a partition on it that is greater in cardinality than the set of singleton subsets of $X$.

> Can $X$ be a standard stage $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy?

> Can $X$ be a  non-standard stage $V_{\alpha'}$ of the cumulative hierarchy?

About the second question what I mean is there is a non-well founded model of $\sf ZF$ such that $\alpha'$ is seen as an ordinal internally but externally it is a transitive set of transitive sets but has subsets of it that are infinite descending membership chains.

Comment: Partitioning a set into "more" is actually violating the *weak* partition principle. It is a stronger claim.

Comment: You can't have a transitive set of transitive sets which has a descending membership chain. If you are a transitive set, you are well-founded. Full stop. Non-standard ordinals/models/etc. will always have a membership relationship that is not the real $\in$.

Comment: Assuming ZF, a transitive set is ***always*** well-founded. All sets are. Non-standard models have a different membership relation, which means it is irrelevant what is the underlying set.

Comment: I'm speaking about non-well founded models, the background theory for models here is ZF-Reg.  So here we can have those transitive and not well founded.

Comment: We had discussed this over some of your previous questions. There is no reasonable notion for "non-standard ordinals" the way you thinking about it; there is even less of a way to define $V_\alpha$ in those cases.

Comment: No what we were discussing is something different. I'm speaking about things that externally seen in a way that is different from internally about those ordinals, which is known to be consistent, a result going back to Mostowski I suppose. But what we've disuccsed before was something that is completely internal, which cannot be as you proved in those threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking whether or not a $V_\alpha$ could violate the partition principle, the answer is easily yes.

As we all know, it is always the case that $\Bbb R$ can be partitioned into $\aleph_1$ parts; but it is consistent that there is no injection from $\omega_1$ into the reals. Next, observe that $V_{\omega+1}$ is exactly the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.

Comment: What about the non-standard stages?

Comment: That's an internal statement. I'm not sure what standard/non-standard have to do with it.

Comment: I mean can we consistently say that we have a non-well founded model of $\sf ZF$, where there is a set $V_{\alpha'}$ in that model where $\alpha'$ is externally a non-standard ordinal (as described above) and such that this model satisfies that $V_{\alpha'}$ violates the weak PP

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Take $\alpha'$ to be the $\omega+1$ of any model of "ZF + PP fails at $V_{\omega+1}$" which is not an $\omega$-model.